# html tags in title, e.g. s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶

Tags: support, titles

I thought it was a good idea to edit the title of the following question:
[What is the source of this E̶r̶d̶ő̶s̶ quote?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145475/what-is-the-source-of-this-erdos-quote)

I wanted to strike through (<s>like this</s>) the name Erdős, but apparently the html tag does not work for titles

```
<s>...</s>
```

Is this a bug or is this restriction intended? Is there a reason why we should not allow strike through of characters?
The question [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) explains what subset of html is allowed in questions; what is the subset that is allowed for titles?

Comment: I retagged [meta-tag:support] instead of [meta-tag:bug] to avoid somebody else having to add a status-tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Already for comments the formatting one can use/that is not escaped is a lot more restricted see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/editing-help#comment-formatting. I think for titles really every HTML is escaped; I do not have a very clear source for this but see for example this meta.SO question [Is it possible to use <sub>HTML</sub> in question titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82013/is-it-possible-to-use-subhtml-sub-in-question-titles)

For strike through specifically I believe (but not certain)  you could do it using Unicode instead.