# What is the source of this strange title strike?

Tags: support

[image: Title Strike]

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/145475/6094).

Comment: Looks fine on my chrome.

Comment: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1095/html-tags-in-title-e-g-strike-through

Comment: Oh, I see! The point is that the quote is not due to Erdős. And the strike only spans the middle three letters, somehwat unevenly. Sorry!